# How do I change the order of integration for cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: integration

I have: $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{z/3}r^3\,dr\,dz\,d\theta.$$

I'm having trouble understanding how to change the order of integration if it's needed. And also I was wondering, would this be an example of Fubini's Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fubini's Theorem is for fixed intervals, like:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^2 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^2\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \iint_{[0,2]\times [0,1]}f(x,y)\,dA
$$
In your case, you can move $d\theta$ around, like this:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{z/3}r^3\,dr\,dz\,d\theta
&= \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{z/3}r^3\,dr\,d\theta\,dz \\
&= \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{z/3} \int_{0}^{2\pi}r^3\,d\theta\,dr\,dz
\end{align}$$
But you need to be careful with the intervals when swapping $dz$ and $d\theta$. It's not always trivial, so you should first draw a diagram with the region you want to integrate:

[image: region]

Then try to work out the intervals:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{z/3}r^3\,dr\,dz
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{3r}^{3}r^3\,dz\,dr
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! So, is there a trick to tell what specific order to use? Or is the diagram the only way to tell for sure?

Comment: It depends so much on the problem... sometimes you already know the region and you have to choose your own parametrization and order of integration. Sometimes the order is given and you want to invert it. In that case, the diagram usually helps.

Comment: So if I'm already given an integral with limits, like this problem, then I just choose my own order?

Comment: In this case it's not worth changing the order (remember that if you do, you have to change the intervals). You choose the order when, for example, the problem gives you a region and a function and you have to write the integral yourself.